# App Inventor 2 Webviewstring to Javascript: Defining an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, app-inventor

OK. What I'm trying to do is to pass an array via the webviewstring. for this, I use blocks to join list items into this: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]. I pass it through, and define this:

```
var itemlist = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString();
```

but when I try to call item 0 in the array, it gives me this: `[` and as item 1, it gives `"`, and item 2, it gives `i`.

If I use

```
document.getElementById("list0").innerHTML = itemlist;
```

it returns `["item1", "item2", "item3"];`

What I believe happens is that it puts the whole webviewstring inside brackets like this: (`["item1", "item2", "item3"];`), so when I call itemlist, it also returns the `;` at the end.

Can anyone tell me how I can translate my webviewstring into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to pass the data in csv format from App Inventor to the HTML file

[image]

and then convert it into an array in the HTML file like this

```
 // get the table to display from the window.AppInventor object and split at new line
 var urlArray = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString().split("\n");
```

see also a complete example [here](https://puravidaapps.com/table.php)

Comment: Thanks Taifun. You're a great help.